# Transposing data to become a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
|   | x_id | x_name | has_policy | payment_name | count |
|---|------|--------|------------|--------------|-------|
| 0 | 2    | two    | 0          | Hybrid       | 58    |
| 1 | 2    | two    | 1          | Hybrid       | 2     |
| 2 | 5    | five   | 1          | Excl         | 13    |
| 3 | 5    | five   | 0          | Excl         | 70    |
| 4 | 5    | five   | 0          | Agen         | 811   |
| 5 | 5    | five   | 1          | Agen         | 279   |
| 6 | 5    | five   | 1          | Hybrid       | 600   |
| 7 | 5    | five   | 0          | Hybrid       | 2819  |
```

I would like to have the combination of `has_policy` and `payment_name` to become a column, with the respective `count`. Expected output would look like this:

```
| id | name | no_policy_hybrid | no_policy_excl | no_policy_agen | policy_hybrid | policy_excl | policy_agen |
|----|------|------------------|----------------|----------------|---------------|-------------|-------------|
| 2  | two  | 58               | 0              | 0              | 2             | 0           | 0           |
| 5  | five | 2819             | 70             | 811            | 600           | 13          | 279         |
```

I was looking at the documentation for both [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) and [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and I'm unsure which would be best to use, though I feel transpose does make more sense for this use case since the count column is already an aggregation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea is pivoting by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), sorting `MultiIndex` and flatten:

```
df['has_policy'] = df['has_policy'].map({0:'no_policy', 1:'policy'})
df = df.set_index(['x_id','x_name','has_policy','payment_name'])['count'].unstack([2,3], fill_value=0).sort_index(axis=1, level=0)
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   x_id x_name  no_policy_Agen  no_policy_Excl  no_policy_Hybrid  policy_Agen  \
0     2    two               0               0                58            0   
1     5   five             811              70              2819          279   

   policy_Excl  policy_Hybrid  
0            0              2  
1           13            600
```

Another idea if necessary aggregate with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and `sum`:

```
df['has_policy'] = df['has_policy'].map({0:'no_policy', 1:'policy'})
df = df.pivot_table(index=['x_id','x_name'],
                    columns=['has_policy','payment_name'], 
                    values='count',
                    aggfunc='sum',
                    fill_value=0).sort_index(axis=1, level=0)
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   x_id x_name  no_policy_Agen  no_policy_Excl  no_policy_Hybrid  policy_Agen  \
0     2    two               0               0                58            0   
1     5   five             811              70              2819          279   

   policy_Excl  policy_Hybrid  
0            0              2  
1           13            600
```

Comment: First solutions works great. I end up with a column `no_policy_nan` but every row is 0 so I can probably just drop it. Also, quick follow up Q. How could I add more columns to the index here for example if the original dataframe had another column `country`, would it be a matter of only putting this in the `set_index()`, maybe after `x_name`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), with [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), and flatten the MultiIndex columns with [to_flat_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_flat_index.html) :

```
res = (
    df.replace({"has_policy": {0: "no_policy", 1: "policy"}})
    .pivot(index=["x_id", "x_name"], columns=["has_policy", "payment_name"])
    .droplevel(0, 1)
)

res.columns = res.columns.to_flat_index().str.join("_")

res.fillna(0).reset_index()


  x_id  x_name  no_policy_Hybrid    policy_Hybrid   policy_Excl no_policy_Excl  no_policy_Agen  policy_Agen
0   2   two     58.0                 2.0             0.0         0.0     0.0    0.0
1   5   five    2819.0              600.0           13.0         70.0   811.0   279.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
grouped = df.groupby(('x_name', 'x_id', 'has_policy', 'payment_name'))
counts = grouped['count'].sum().reset_index()
counts


x_name  x_id    has_policy  payment_name    count
0   five    5   0   Agen    811
1   five    5   0   Excl    70
2   five    5   0   Hybrid  2819
3   five    5   1   Agen    279
4   five    5   1   Excl    13
5   five    5   1   Hybrid  600
6   two     2   0   Hybrid  58
7   two     2   1   Hybrid  2


counts['policy_payment'] = counts['has_policy'].map({0 : 'no_policy', 1: 'policy'}) \
                             + '_' \
                             + counts['payment_name'].map(lambda s: s.lower())


table = counts.pivot(index='x_name', columns='policy_payment', values='count').fillna(0)
table

policy_payment  no_policy_agen  no_policy_excl  no_policy_hybrid    policy_agen policy_excl policy_hybrid
x_name                      
five    811.0   70.0    2819.0  279.0   13.0    600.0
two       0.0    0.0      58.0    0.0    0.0      2.0
```

In pandas 1.1.0 you should be able to set `index=[x_id, x_name]` in `pd.DataFrame.pivot` to get exactly what you described.